# Will the Cardano Rust project eventually allow you to write Smart Contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, trust

Discovered this: https://cardanorust.iohk.io/

Looks great. Any rough sense on when Cardano Rust will support smart contracts? Is it being worked on now? Would be amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the project in question is a toolbox that has been used in the Byron era of Cardano and could be considered outdated right now.

When someone [implements the Cardano node in Rust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wu-M5PuG9h8&), it will have to have the support for Smart Contract to match the ledger specification.

Answer (score 0):

The last commit was Feb. 4th, 2020. So, no it's not being worked on—at least not recently. See the [Github repo here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/rust-cardano).